# Extract email addresses from log with grep or sed

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep, cut

```
Jan 23 00:46:24 portal postfix/smtp[31481]: 1B1653FEA1: to=<wanted1918_ke@yahoo.com>, relay=mta5.am0.yahoodns.net[98.138.112.35]:25, delay=5.4, delays=0.02/3.2/0.97/1.1, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host mta5.am0.yahoodns.net[98.138.112.35] said: 554 delivery error: dd This user doesn't have a yahoo.com account (wanted1918_ke@yahoo.com) [0] - mta1321.mail.ne1.yahoo.com (in reply to end of DATA command))
Jan 23 00:46:24 portal postfix/smtp[31539]: AF40C3FE99: to=<devi_joshi@yahoo.com>, relay=mta7.am0.yahoodns.net[98.136.217.202]:25, delay=5.9, delays=0.01/3.1/0.99/1.8, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host mta7.am0.yahoodns.net[98.136.217.202] said: 554 delivery error: dd This user doesn't have a yahoo.com account (devi_joshi@yahoo.com) [0] - mta1397.mail.gq1.yahoo.com (in reply to end of DATA command))
```

From above maillog I would like to extract the email addresses enclosed between the angular brackets `< ... >` eg. `to=<wanted1918_ke@yahoo.com>` to `wanted1918_ke@yahoo.com`

I am using `cut -d' ' -f7` to extract emails but I am curious if there is a more flexible way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With GNU grep, just use a regular expression containing a look behind and look ahead:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=to=<).*(?=>)' file
wanted1918_ke@yahoo.com
devi_joshi@yahoo.com
```

This says: hey, extract all the strings preceded by `to=<` and followed by `>`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `awk` like this:

```
awk -F'to=<|>,' '{print $2}' the.log
```

I'm splitting the line by `to=<` or `>,` and print the second field.

Answer (score 3):

Just to show a `sed` alternative (requires GNU or BSD/macOS `sed` due to `-E`):

```
sed -E 's/.* to=<(.*)>.*/\1/' file
```

Note how the regex must match the *entire* line so that the substitution of the capture-group match (the email address) yields *only* that match.

A *slightly* more efficient - but perhaps less readable - variation is
`sed -E 's/.* to=<([^>]*).*/\1/' file`

---

A POSIX-compliant formulation is a little more cumbersome due to the legacy syntax required by BREs (*basic* regular expressions):

```
sed 's/.* to=<\(.*\)>.*/\1/' file
```

---

A variation of [fedorqui's helpful GNU `grep` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41872693/45375):

```
grep -Po ' to=<\K[^>]*' file
```

`\K`, which drops everything matched up to that point, is not only syntactically simpler than a look-behind assertion (`(?<=...)`, but also more flexible - it supports *variable*-length expressions - and is *faster* (though that may not matter in many real-world situations; if performance is paramount: see below).

---

#### Performance comparison

Here's how the various solutions on this page compare in terms of performance.

Note that this may not matter much in many use cases, but gives insight into:

- the relative performance of the various standard utilities
- for a given utility, how tweaking the regex can make a difference.

The absolute values are not important, but the relative performance hopefully provides some insight. See the bottom for the script that produced these numbers, which were obtained on a late-2012 27" iMac running macOS 10.12.3, using a 250,000-line input file created by replicating the sample input from the question, averaging the timings of 10 runs each.

```
Mawk                            0.364s
GNU grep, \K, non-backtracking  0.392s
GNU awk                         0.830s
GNU grep, \K                    0.937s
GNU grep, (?>=...)              1.639s
BSD grep + cut                  2.733s
GNU grep + cut                  3.697s
BSD awk                         3.785s
BSD sed, non-backtracking       7.825s
BSD sed                         8.414s
GNU sed                         16.738s
GNU sed, non-backtracking       17.387s
```

A few conclusions:

- The specific implementation of a given utility matters.
- `grep` is generally a good choice, even if it needs to be combined with `cut`
- Tweaking the regex to avoid backtracking and look-behind assertions can make a difference.
- GNU `sed` is surprisingly slow, whereas GNU `awk` is faster than BSD `awk`. Strangely, the (partially) non-backtracking solution is *slower* with GNU `sed`.

---

Here's the script that produced the timings above; note that the `g`-prefixed commands are *GNU* utilities that were installed on macOS via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh); similarly, `mawk` was installed via Homebrew.

Note that "non-backtracking" only applies *partially* to some of the commands.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Define the test commands.
test01=( 'BSD sed'                        sed -E 's/.*to=<(.*)>.*/\1/' )
test02=( 'BSD sed, non-backtracking'      sed -E 's/.*to=<([^>]*).*/\1/' )
# ---
test03=( 'GNU sed'                        gsed -E 's/.*to=<(.*)>.*/\1/' )
test04=( 'GNU sed, non-backtracking'      gsed -E 's/.*to=<([^>]*).*/\1/' )
# ---
test05=( 'BSD awk'                        awk  -F' to=<|>,' '{print $2}' )
test06=( 'GNU awk'                        gawk -F' to=<|>,' '{print $2}' )
test07=( 'Mawk'                           mawk -F' to=<|>,' '{print $2}' )
#--
test08=( 'GNU grep, (?>=...)'             ggrep -Po '(?<= to=<).*(?=>)' )
test09=( 'GNU grep, \K'                   ggrep -Po ' to=<\K.*(?=>)' )
test10=( 'GNU grep, \K, non-backtracking' ggrep -Po ' to=<\K[^>]*' )
# --
test11=( 'BSD grep + cut'                 "{ grep -o  ' to=<[^>]*' | cut  -d'<' -f2; }" )
test12=( 'GNU grep + cut'                 "{ ggrep -o ' to=<[^>]*' | gcut -d'<' -f2; }" )

# Determine input and output files.
inFile='file'
# NOTE: Do NOT use /dev/null, because GNU grep apparently takes a shortcut
#       when it detects stdout going nowhere, which distorts the timings.
#       Use dev/tty if you want to see stdout in the terminal (will print
#       as a single block across all tests before the results are reported).
outFile="/tmp/out.$$"
# outFile='/dev/tty'

# Make `time` only report the overall elapsed time.
TIMEFORMAT='%6R'

# How many runs per test whose timings to average.
runs=10

# Read the input file up to even the playing field, so that the first command
# doesn't take the hit of being the first to load the file from disk.
echo "Warming up the cache..."
cat "$inFile" >/dev/null

# Run the tests.
echo "Running $(awk '{print NF}' <<<"${!test*}") test(s), averaging the timings of $runs run(s) each; this may take a while..."
{
    for n in ${!test*}; do    
        arrRef="$n[@]"
        test=( "${!arrRef}" )
        # Print test description.
        printf '%s\t' "${test[0]}"
        # Execute test command.
        if (( ${#test[@]} == 2 )); then # single-token command? assume `eval` must be used.
          time for (( n = 0; n < runs; n++ )); do eval "${test[@]: 1}" < "$inFile" >"$outFile"; done
        else # multiple command tokens? assume that they form a simple command that can be invoked directly.
          time for (( n = 0; n < runs; n++ )); do "${test[@]: 1}" "$inFile" >"$outFile"; done
        fi
    done
} 2>&1 | 
  sort -t$'\t' -k2,2n | 
    awk -v runs="$runs" '
      BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} { avg = sprintf("%.3f", $2/runs); print $1, avg "s" }
    ' | column -s$'\t' -t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'[<>]' '{print $2}' file

wanted1918_ke@yahoo.com
devi_joshi@yahoo.com
```

Comment: That's probably too weak. Anchoring it at `to=<` is imo a good idea.