# Get a list of unique sender(from=) domains in postfix maillog

Tags: postfix-mta, logfile, mail-server

I am currenlty trying to extract all the sender domains from `maillog`. I am able to do some of that with the below command but the output is not quite what I desired. What would be the best approach to retrieve a unique list of sender domain from maillog?

`grep from= /var/log/maillog | awk '{print $7}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n`

output

```
1 from=<user@test.com>,
1 from=<apache@app1.com>,
2 from=<bounceld_5BFa-bx0p-P3tQ-67Nn@example.com>,
2 from=<bounceld_19iI-HqaS-usVU-fqe5@example.com>,
12 reject:
666 from=<>,
```

desired output

```
test.com
app1.com
example.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [useless use of `grep`](https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#grep); if you are using Awk anyway, you don't really need `grep` at all.

```
awk '$7 ~ /from=.*@/{split($7, a, /@/); ++count[a[2]] }
  END { for(dom in count) print count[dom], dom }' /var/log/maillog
```

Collecting the `count`s in an associative array does away with the need to call `sort` and `uniq`, too. Obviously, if you don't care about the count, don't print `count[dom]` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the answer:

```
grep from= /var/log/maillog | awk '{print $7}' | grep -Po '(?=@).{1}\K.*(?=>)' | sort -n | uniq -c
```

... change last items to "| sort | uniq" to remove the counts.

**References:**

https://www.baeldung.com/linux/bash-remove-first-characters {1}\K use

[Extract email addresses from log with grep or sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41872634/extract-email-addresses-from-log-with-grep-or-sed) -Po grep function